# why does JavaMail to Exchange throw MessagingException 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated?

Tags: exchange-server, jakarta-mail

I've been researching this for awhile and tried several different combinations of properties and keep getting this error. We are able to successfully send out emails with other smtp servers (and different properties) with no problems, but Exchange won't work.

Other answers on this topic mention that you need version 1.4.3 or newer version of JavaMail, because Exchange servers need NTLM. I'm using JavaMail 1.4.7. Other answers say Exchange doesn't support SMTP by default.

Here's the latest code :

```
// this is inside a Junit
String emailTo = "me@gmail.com";
String emailFrom = "me@mycompany.com";
String message = "testing exchange";
String host = "smtp.office365.com";
String user = "obfuscated";
String password = "obfuscated";

StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder(message);

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
props.put("mail.from", "me@mycompany.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
try {
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(as_email_from));
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(as_email_to));
    message.setSubject("Testing exchange server");                
    message.setContent(body.toString(), "text/html");
    message.setSentDate(new Date());

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, 587, smtpSettings.getUser(), smtpSettings.getPswd());
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
   private PasswordAuthentication authentication;
   public Authenticator() {
       String username = "myuser";
       String password = "mypass";
       authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
   }
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
       return authentication;
   }
}
```

and here's the debug :

```
DEBUG: SMTPTransport connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587

DEBUG SMTP SENT: EHLO Brian-PC
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 250-BY2PR01CA020.outlook.office365.com Hello [207.250.96.62]
250-SIZE 78643200
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING

DEBUG SMTP Found extension "SIZE", arg "78643200"
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "AUTH", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
DEBUG SMTP SENT: MAIL FROM:<me@mycompany.com>
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the debug output, I believe you're not actually using JavaMail 1.4.7.  Check your CLASSPATH, the lib directories on your server, etc.

Comment: what in the debug output tells you that?

Comment: The format of the protocol trace.  The format was changed in more recent versions.  Also, recent versions will print the version number at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the issue. I'm now able to email via an Exchange server. And I did see the 1.4.7 version printed at the beginning of the debug.

Comment: Great!  You might want to consider upgrading to JavaMail 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Exchange server requires TLS to be enabled, if it's required, enable TLS by setting up this attribute

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

This solved my issue.